# Ofuscar código javascript

Tags: javascript, html

He ofuscado mi código JS en [javascriptobfuscator.com](http://javascriptobfuscator.com), pero mi sorpresa es que en herramientas como http://www.jsnice.org/, poniendo el código ofuscado te lo descifra prácticamente al 100% en un momento.

¿Hay alguna forma de ofuscar el código y que no pueda ser descifrado?

Comment: ¿De verdad?, no te gustaría de nuevo pensar la posibilidad de ofuscar tu código...

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta, si precisamente he ofuscado el código es porque prefiero que nadie lo pueda ver.

Comment: El asunto con los métodos para minimizar tu código del lado del cliente es que al final puedes aplicarle ingeniería inversa, y por tanto llegar a saber cómo funcionan, es por esto que lo ideal es que el código que llegue al cliente no posea datos sensibles. Mayormente se minimiza el código por el peso de los archivos y no tanto por seguridad.

Comment: Entonces me estás diciendo que no existe la forma de encriptar el código javascript de un .html para que nadie lo pueda leer e interpretar? @learnercys

Comment: Cada lenguaje tiene sus pros y contras, si quieres proteger datos o procedemientos hazlo a la parte del servidor y con Javascript llamadas con Ajax a esos procesos.

Answer (score 13):

> Hay alguna forma de ofuscar el código y que no pueda ser descifrado?

***NO LA HAY,*** pues ofuscar es la transformación de un pedazo código en otro código diferente: **difícil de leer para una persona, pero equivalente para una maquina**. Aunque no es totalmente reversible (se perderán los nombres originales de variables y funciones) sigue generando los mismos resultados y aunque no estén tales pistas, igual será relativamente fácil analizar como funciona.

La ofuscación es una forma de [seguridad por oscuridad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguridad_por_oscuridad), y no es considerada una buena práctica pues **no elimina el vector de ataque** simplemente lo estarías tapando/ocultando.

La forma de segurizar un sistema -cualquier sistema-, es hacerlo en su diseño; Ocultando el código, simplemente haces un poco mas difícil encontrar una vulnerabilidad pero la vulnerabilidad sigue allí.

Answer (score 4):

La idea de ofuscar es dificultar la comprensión o lectura, solo añade unos pasos más al proceso de entender tu código, mas no se refiere a hacerlo imposible de entender. Si fuera imposible,¿cómo lo interpretaría el navegador?

Como indica @learnercys, lo mejor es evitar los datos sensibles en el lado del cliente, trata de mantener la lógica de tu sistema separada de la presentación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta herramienta hace mejor lo que quieres hacer, y deja el código irreconocible. (http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/) A ver si te sirve @DavidMatas

Answer (score 0):

Yo también ando investigando la manera de poder hacerlo más difícil de entender y copiar. Como bien dices, esta herramienta http://javascriptobfuscator.com/ al parecer hace una buena ofuscación pero es fácil de obtener el código casi 100% desofuscado.
Un amigo me sugirió esta página http://myobfuscate.com/ , podrías probarlo.
Otros me recomendaron una opción de pago como JScrambler pero no lo he llegado a probar aún.