# ¿De qué forma puedo encriptar u ofuscar mi pagina web?

Tags: php, html, encriptación

Pueden decirme algún método o class para encriptar un documento PHP o HTML.
He investigado un poco en la internet y no hay ningún material para descargar porque al parecer hay que pagar, pero no hay alguna forma de encriptar con base64, o algo así. Porque no quiero que mi código esté abierto para cualquiera.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token_ap']="1234567890";
if (!empty($_SESSION['token_ap'])){
    $token_ap=$_SESSION['token_ap'];
    require 'link/link.php';
    if ($sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE token_ap='$token_ap'")){
        $fila=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($fila==0){
            header('location: logout.php');
            mysqli_close($link);
        }elseif ($fila==1) {
            //Logged in
            $usuario_log=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
            if($num_entradas=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM entradas WHERE token_ap_en='$token_ap' ORDER BY fecha_en DESC")){
                $entradas = mysqli_fetch_array($num_entradas);
                $numero_entradas = mysqli_num_rows($num_entradas);
            }
        }
    }else{
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
}else{
    header('location: logout.php');
}
?>
```

Que quede así como...

```
<?php
$xf56ceb6="\142\x61\163\145\x36\64\137\x64\145\x63\x6f\144\x65";@eval($xf56ceb6(
"Ly9OcnRQUy8yM0p0alhXZXphYVZTbERvdGtvZkxNVlNGMm1LWnZHSzhoL1ZYS1EzRS9mYzhyUGtyY0Z
ZY0hCdDBES3FFQmN3ajgrMytQWEViZmVxTWcvU0w5U0diZloycStkdWNSNURhbEVJL01RV1pTWVhBZGp
0KzZmME4zQjdGOWNNM21FTVVJQVZyaGZzOC91eW5xd3dLY0h4bVFucmptSDlFL05zaHN1UjJoM0N4Tmp
4Y3NxRHVvWU0zVGU0YThOV0duelFJMVhzOEY5d05Hc29PcDVtYzJzNTFyVEU5NlQ3OWVlOCtsUzRMcHV
HWUpnalRoSnhCNGdSdEJ4SkZaMWpHNEU0b3cwUlIxZ1dpTkpyeVVyU3lhMmZQNURPczlmN3pBOE5tRzZ
yeG9wM3NUam5aMHpEODh0dGZkSVJUaW5CRkRDZ0RJZnpULzhWNTBFc09nRTE0ZnM2dTdHR0hyTCszS2l
jRFNvaDMzeEd0RUZBN0VTQVBjb2pnc1NHTnRFRngxR0tJbURrdmVidXdPaGswZjEzWUxFTlEzYkFCNi9
yZkZrb1krRVhGUTdLa0c4WnJTVE5KeVVPY2xUMURyZ3k4Ym9COUxyeHAzbmNDMFlWdlVTTk1tS3R0SDk
vV3MwanR3Q0tkeXJXZjBDL2s2ME9yRlJWYXBZM3h4RDM4UHBXYUM4VUVhcUg0NFJrT0F5a29vWC9VbHZ
UYVkwM3BaNlBNRWplckh6a0JkMDFqKzhMRnJTZXl1VUZ4NWJzVWVGOXUydjNKd3l2cUEwd0ZleGpyczQ
5bDc1UHVqOUdjZ3lUeXdMSmtqWmlVVnEyZDVqdkFWWXhud1JwTFVVdWFTNW9nSitFZTUyeWNhbGhhby9
KRDhJT0EwSW5VcTVMb2VtUVlFZHR1S2ozbWJCYitBUklCZnQzT2gyd0owdElrTWxIZGFaUGoxc1BobHY
xMk45cWhrOS9YYUJqeEZrc3AyVnRDQzdzQ3VMVWdRa2toYWJnMHVQOFpXRnh5MCtZUWpCaC80T0lGUWw
wSUhCZy8ySk9kY2dMMDZnbG5jZlpwTHg4endWazVnRHRCRVlERFRybTdWSWJaZTdFK1VHQW1CaGhlTHV
ZVjl0MEZpRW11RzU4VFZ4YW1Jamd3RWN2eXJvZkdwazlKVGkrTWV2TklNdjhhREIxeVhYZGlHZnFKbE1
ZM2s1L2pXTHRYaFVmZGdWMlY5dkhSeGh2RTFESW5ibFFOdnh1eUx5REVIWmZ4N0hGbFJ1ZVYxaTJ2WFZ
wVHljY0pwRVp6MFpFZXpJMFFBaFFSMTY5UW9hbE1qVUZyU0pwNTZ6OGY9OnY3dnBwaVFmY2Zvc21Wcnp
tb2JzOCt4aU5OPT06MDVyMTI1MDkKJHZhZTlhYjBiPSJcMTQ1IjskeWZiOGY0M2Y9IlwxNDciOyR4ZjU
2Y2ViNj0iXDE0MiI7JGY5ZjJhZmU3PSJcMTYzIjskdjY2M2QwOTM9IlwxNDYiOyR3YTNiMDg4Nj0iXDE
2MyI7JGYyMjc3NGUzPSJceDcyIjskcmM0NDg4M2M9Ilx4NzMiOyRzMDQ0NzE1Yz0iXHg3MCI7JHJjNDQ
4ODNjLj0iXHg3NCI7JHdhM2IwODg2Lj0iXHg3NCI7JHMwNDQ3MTVjLj0iXHg3MiI7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0
iXHg2MSI7JGY5ZjJhZmU3Lj0iXHg2OCI7JHlmYjhmNDNmLj0iXHg3YSI7JGYyMjc3NGUzLj0iXDE0NSI
7JHZhZTlhYjBiLj0iXHg3OCI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXHg2OSI7JHlmYjhmNDNmLj0iXHg2OSI7JHZhZTl
hYjBiLj0iXDE2MCI7JGY5ZjJhZmU3Lj0iXDE0MSI7JHJjNDQ4ODNjLj0iXHg3MiI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0
iXDE1NCI7JGYyMjc3NGUzLj0iXDE2MyI7JHMwNDQ3MTVjLj0iXDE0NSI7JHdhM2IwODg2Lj0iXHg3MiI
7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0iXHg3MyI7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0iXHg2NSI7JHJjNDQ4ODNjLj0iXDE0MyI7JHlmYjh
mNDNmLj0iXDE1NiI7JGYyMjc3NGUzLj0iXHg2NSI7JGY5ZjJhZmU3Lj0iXHgzMSI7JHdhM2IwODg2Lj0
iXHg1ZiI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXHg2NSI7JHMwNDQ3MTVjLj0iXHg2NyI7JHZhZTlhYjBiLj0iXHg2YyI
7JHJjNDQ4ODNjLj0iXDE1NSI7JHZhZTlhYjBiLj0iXHg2ZiI7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0iXDY2IjskZjIyNzc
0ZTMuPSJceDc0IjskdjY2M2QwOTMuPSJcMTM3Ijskd2EzYjA4ODYuPSJceDcyIjskczA0NDcxNWMuPSJ
ceDVmIjskeWZiOGY0M2YuPSJcMTQ2IjskdjY2M2QwOTMuPSJceDY3IjskdmFlOWFiMGIuPSJcMTQ0Ijs
keWZiOGY0M2YuPSJcMTU0Ijskd2EzYjA4ODYuPSJcMTU3IjskeGY1NmNlYjYuPSJceDM0IjskczA0NDc
xNWMuPSJceDcyIjskcmM0NDg4M2MuPSJcMTYwIjskdmFlOWFiMGIuPSJceDY1IjskczA0NDcxNWMuPSJ
cMTQ1IjskdjY2M2QwOTMuPSJcMTQ1IjskeWZiOGY0M2YuPSJcMTQxIjskeGY1NmNlYjYuPSJcMTM3Ijs
kd2EzYjA4ODYuPSJceDc0IjskeGY1NmNlYjYuPSJcMTQ0Ijskd2EzYjA4ODYuPSJcNjEiOyR5ZmI4ZjQ
zZi49IlwxNjQiOyRzMDQ0NzE1Yy49Ilx4NzAiOyR2NjYzZDA5My49Ilx4NzQiOyR4ZjU2Y2ViNi49Ilx
4NjUiOyR2NjYzZDA5My49Ilx4NWYiOyR5ZmI4ZjQzZi49IlwxNDUiOyR3YTNiMDg4Ni49Ilw2MyI7JHM
wNDQ3MTVjLj0iXDE1NCI7JHMwNDQ3MTVjLj0iXHg2MSI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXHg2MyI7JHhmNTZjZWI
2Lj0iXDE0MyI7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0iXHg2ZiI7JHMwNDQ3MTVjLj0iXDE0MyI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXDE
1NyI7JHMwNDQ3MTVjLj0iXHg2NSI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXDE1NiI7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0iXDE0NCI7JHY
2NjNkMDkzLj0iXDE2NCI7JHhmNTZjZWI2Lj0iXDE0NSI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXHg2NSI7JHY2NjNkMDk
zLj0iXDE1NiI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXDE2NCI7JHY2NjNkMDkzLj0iXDE2MyI7JGo5MTlhNTEwPSR2YWU
5YWIwYigiXHgyOCIsX19GSUxFX18pO0BldmFsKCRyYzQ0ODgzYygkZjlmMmFmZTcoJHMwNDQ3MTVjKCJ
cNTdceDVjXHgyOFwxMzRceDIyXDU2XDUyXDEzNFx4MjJceDVjXHgyOVw1NyIsIlw1MFw0Mlw0Mlx4Mjk
iLCRzMDQ0NzE1YygiXDU3XDE1XHg3Y1wxMlw1NyIsIiIsJHY2NjNkMDkzKCRmMjI3NzRlMygkajkxOWE
1MTApKSkpKSwiXHgzMlx4NjNcNzFcMTQzXHg2M1wxNDNcMTQ0XDE0MVw3MVw2M1x4MzVcMTQzXDcxXDE
0MVw2M1x4MzlceDY2XDY3XDE0M1x4MzdceDM5XDE0NVx4NjVcNzFceDM1XDY3XDE0Mlx4MzFceDM5XDE
0MVw2Mlx4NjVceDY2XHgzM1x4MzBceDY0XHg2NFx4NjZceDM4XDY2Iik/JHlmYjhmNDNmKCR4ZjU2Y2V
iNigkd2EzYjA4ODYoIkNJS0tkaGo2UmkyS2ozMjR0aytwUjVyT3BKbWFveHNNbUs2azJtYWE5Q0tHNTh
PWkRGVGNGemhnRHZkdWk4NnBjUTVNRGkzNzE4OVdMRzhidHM2cEFDNnF4bThIOUtDdmtaOVc1ZzhqOEZ
xMEhlOUcrcXMvZVUvOTg5cklXMGtCNEN4S3drWTBTa2cvUittS2Y2OUdDbHc1citBaUdoWG8vajA0THd
rT1RCbkM0U3BWL0dYdWk0SWsrZi80ei8xMzdaR0VVamUvOXA5L2Z3MWgvLzYvbUE5Ly9uL3RpLy9DOUN
waURLM2JxZ2M0R2JLY0xEckNldHZzNFMzV01tVnZWelIrSkhiVS9DdjJxTnVkZGVhSDVTRGVrbVB5a1Z
lUzNTMUpsR0lUVDRXcU5YVGxlaklTeEplS0c1ZXlMbFRFVG9TbFhNSVdrWEgrUml2NXVaNFNEK2VSYW1
MWWpFUEZCZHprWmFqRGVIK2pDUkhaeHZmbXgzbDgwZ2ZEalZEQzJwZkd1RmxZUm5Ld21idHcwb1NnK0R
RT3Q1QjRhcmVPa0V4R3V6bm9CU3RMaXVnYnVyUGVodFJSamovNHZUU3p1NXE2RjRBZkF5U2pKeHZ6Wjh
DQjhIcGRDeVJ2cU12eWIyOHVIMFVxM2pMKzNjdWVWZEd0RU9xa2QxWXJnTGdKdVZyQTduTWY3anVWemZ
SSzJ6NDhEOHI5RGY2MGwxbDNWVFdzRjRBQWhVMUtLMG10amlKd0loYWRRdjBCQ2RiK1hCdnlzZEQxMm5
lMzJXUjVUV0hacmJ2WGx0TEpVZ0M2K2RTbUZSRFR1dG5ScFhpZ0hCKytDcmlYWjNYb1ZkVG1xOXUybXp
XNUFqTGhBNGNObzJ3V3pGdm51SGlkZUloZTVFWHpqNFJOSU9oZnE0Ni9zUVkzZlNieDJ0Z1c4SDh6YkU
zV252ZUY0RHA5cFhrVkcxclJrUjdZcVlFN0xjV1JuZ3RBbWVFSU11clM4UHR1aTBob2s2dlc5VndraXJ
SZUNZMzh5VzZYNkVYclIxSTVZRjAxR253VXJNaDFlR0F1YXFxc3EybzR5SldVRU1JSVFyUnp2Uk1WRmF
kOGNDeTZkNzV1c3ZrMDhqME9kclN2OFhMR3I3bEM3U1JVSDVWMXg1TnVpdkxESGFHNG9ibFpKalVsckF
IWWZOS090VVB1Tm92WVhKMmJFY0NrdVY3dzBGZ1crSjJWbUsxcTlOSjgzVjdMbWhjanJtaGNYbVd0eG8
xUXptRUxEc0JTbGFpb20vYXhaMXJNVXZJdDhVUGEwSWpsNFNFMTRBSzNxMCszUzdjT003aXd1VjhRdzV
lWFVuMG5yaHFPeUNteTc2VENrcWpKUXhNOXBPdU0wbjNYWDk2akNPSlVoKzJBNWZYUXN3RWc2Y2VEN0w
rRENEd3lWbDE3N2M2QmR3QW1ONzRQemEzbjA5M05YRTIvT0lja3ZTWW5Pd1dPNEZ2S2FsVG9aQnhvMzV
3SDdoeFZMSHRXaExyNFU4TnJXQ053eW1jYnNyNHhzYm9tNS91UmRIMDlQTERIeHFYcmt2dExidit6YTZ
WdHhBaloxK3d1TnpFczJMbVhYQ1Y2aTN3cW9zMktLQ1gzYnVqUFBhQnI4VGpZMDZWaVZhcWd3T3hCTU5
yMzVGWHBUTEYyZXRQL3gvVjA3SmRHT25WT2Jyd1VZM2tjenlQZG5RNHNDMVRpajdra1RoUVRSZ2JOM0h
kSm5YWVhMeTU0WjU5aUdlb3NHcFRGUkJ4ZFFOVHZsVXZ0SWVrd2s4UHlUbjB2enhEekVRbW0xN0lUNTV
JSmtaTlcybFVDZWF0cU1WTEx2cEFiQTV0NXU3dEc1MkxZcnRrak8yOTN2eVlWZklOWUFVakg3WkV5aFR
aWUZoRE00VUpTNVhTREdpWW5WYThZY3phYWpzekh0T3l4dmZqeGxOTHZydTlGdGlpTDBYRDJ4dEFHdzY
xK2hteGtxcVFEbzRXcUFSV0hodG5GOVQxd3M1RENjbDc3alJPSGIxbzJ3cVR3bTFXb2FVUlVaWkRFWEp
4ZFMyMHFiVDZMTjRqZ2RyMDBOd3UvTG91aVFDbXpJTzlzK2pqTW5iQW9jdWxhZ3l0eWt5aUdFN0tKN3A
4NnQvR2NxeGt2OTdVYllJVVhCZG51cXhmT1N4WHFDcHJKQmZsVVk2dHUzSm5jbmU0TnM2cDJlbSszMTl
OZFJLQ3BPZlBTMCtEQ2RqUnZnUHNWWWdEQXpoRnFNbzZqenZsamNDVHFncGpCUXhOclZYbHlLTG1CaE1
XTWVoNEk0K3cyUkMwOVhpZGVzTElBZi9URy9hMiszV1QwVW14MjJGaXN5ai9wOTc1U2lnV2hKdzRnSCt
Cd1RMd3hkRE1Nd3kxS1pjTzNyenRuSDRvc1Y0ODVOb3Z5R2RLQmthdGp1andPclMvWm4xT2xqL25hUFN
VODdJQm5XM0xsRDZpRWxYZEhoeTZidGhJaHl5bUdtU1lVYzNvUXI5dG9QOW9BNHVDM2tEMXVkNGhJZ3p
iT3NQWnRwVEhzMllIeDFHR29yYjhoMjdkMEt6ai9KTkR3Y25IMlBjdWVLZERjYndoS2lDZTNmWE5KOUx
vbC9HMUEzM1lsbjFId1hpbDBWMXdSd25tdWFkcWxWZTJUUGQza0pqaUxCTWRES0lJcFYzUmd6TXhnTVl
Bd1pnbU5sOGZ2OTU3czd0RUgvbG9FcENQNFM5bzVERFkxOEl0KzNjL1BZZktidEJHVUhkSVJtOWFUenB
hbkVOSVVxNEpjWjRETFUzRUNkK3luWDNYcmFpSjlVYW9udEpRWjRCeksreE1FYUFDbFZsTzZpTzY0dFk
xR1YyM3pBNjBoOGJaWVdFakxVbWxaaGpqWWlMQVhzTEJDU2phdEhqT0NDc2l4eDByU2RRb21zckozaFR
SMjEyYm0ySVhmZHFBRUJ4ejFpbXRmOE81dmRzRVE2WUZYNXhMcFkzZnBjSGhhN1VHTS9CdzFSUGRiRkc
3UXhBTWIvWlEwc0toODRaczMza1NyNlhvcGZtcDlKSzVqeWpzMmNlVDdsTFJ0T21COTg3WWtTVVRnalo
0MVlYYmF2YjRtSlR5NXNGV1JMbmpJWk1NU0kzODd3NmdVRUEraEFsR2xGQjBueHNlVDMwT01KVWF0TWh
jRXJSYm1UZG5uZGdpcU1wVE03NW5oNFJ3T2Z5YWJDSmZXQVRYOWRpVUtBejFtazBpWElKMXkyL29sYmI
2T3VVMzNhLzJjR05PbGY0OW0xS3YwWElBd3g0SXc0N1Y1VTJZVnBQTFZta2x5RUh5LzBJdGlzR242dUR
nRTUvU3Uzakh5QWlBVkJaZkhLb2F3SXBjUjBNUDNud05tZ0FJeXJpYWFFRUYxKzNWb1JDQnZ1NndPNEl
oSUJvMnAzZnRrK2JCNUVIZUpDVjdFaUwwYlZMQ25saWhrOUpHZ2pVT1FxQ1FQakJLbDYxOXMrK3IvIik
pKTokeWZiOGY0M2YoJHhmNTZjZWI2KCR3YTNiMDg4NigiQ01HVWxoalZRYktzNXFYWW9lbGpLcDQwUzh
ua2FaZjU4SitwcDg1Kyt2Nm56SXhWY1BBOU8yMnhDNjRQajlaOGpLLy8rYlVFMTgrU2ptOGp3YWttN0J
xUDhPOHAvTFJFNHZodzMvdVgzOW5TUzkvMmkvSmlpLys0djREZkhYRzQ4dXFCL1pRUjZqc1RpdTRML3U
zUGkxZTZlK3FTL09zNEczN1IzTS8vay83ODQzOFkvQ2FZdk9rNXpEMldVNVpQdjBmczl5S1RITm9Lb0d
HdzZoem15b3RDMDNPbCtSNDBHWmFPTGpnenIrOFBjTVNkZlBvOWl1dm54ZVpxNEVicnZ4YkVjK1ZZQVB
BU1QwUllteE8wR3Mvek5JR2JrY3o2UzJ2V3pTdThBT3ZOU2VPTUxPVzBjaGNkSm9IdkRaamJKanV4WUF
YTHdiTEtHNjBVbWpuOFF1VnYyUTRYZURwY05Cb3R3b0luQUVmSENpVHd0RGtQaHpYQWFOOVQ1S2ZFZ3h
wbFZCRWNWUFBjdDVrdURQdTQ0QW9QWjZuTzVGK3VEOTJLOXp1SUJDaUtTMHEwejBLYVZDRERpd2ZxWlh
DWTZIbEt1aDFhQ2Iwa0ZqeHFxenZ3eHpDTWd5a1liZ1ZzcXZxbGZBY1BKZytnUWdVRFlYRzlJbG1zOEl
nYjExQU5mR2gwbFVsclhNWW4ybVg5RHU2bC9JY3JkcW96Wng1dDFPYldNVXJWWXhleXByQlRReE1JR01
2YzNVSDhvem9wZzBsaTdEc1lISFhNbVl2S2xjYldEYW9mbjJkVlRKSGZMRHAzQU0rMmgyb28yZjNHald
hVitzNE9yQi9tTE1OZ1JuZ1lpbEtpbWl5MWthZ3VhSjZsNEFqN2d1ZFp5TVlSd01zRk8rYjJBUEpmTDR
XdXlQblJDb2hoNjN6RVR2R0VhenFtRHJ1RWpHc0YyRWt2OEpKd3hDcEhvdkZxTHdUVjYrbDFNeU1zbER
Tc2hpeGpEdmJZd3F1M3dWT01aOVJWdW96M3lFTzJHWDhKYjBEYnU1ZmdqYnZkTGNKdDVabFpKR0w1Mmx
qUmFRNlVncVRTRlRnR1dZUFB1OHF6ckpHYitiWUg5MFZRcU5ORzFNTGJEeHJmcTVYYU9ERDBDaW50dTF
ZU0J1R0VqMGtaVnUzMVQ2anlRa0prS2ljMnFHZ0V2ajI2SExLTTNuZ0JwdGdQWnVaN0tFdjI0eHAzTGp
FdW5sc1JTRDVLYkJJOG5vNG1IbWkzSkNkekVSOXJxUVZma3lXVjFHcW1FWCtsNHBhdHRoR050Z0Z2T2p
PU21mMktCbWZOTEtTSWZGM291eSsyVThFZUxVK3JiUnZYU1hia0djWnhwcWQxRkZLbVRQY0xzalVKcFA
3cmlwTlI0U1hjSDc5NG0xdG9lY3JIYjBGQmNoYUdTUzI3ZkUzWVkxQzNGblIwQkoyUkRBcEF1UjVQeXp
tS28xbVZBdWorNU94aWRlQXN1SVpaOXlZcnBVOG1HWURBVy9FMWxvWHZLV1V0Q2dzb3JmYUdPeFNkNXp
vOHpRVEM5ZEYwTGpNSTNVVGh0T041SkR6MjQzWjEwTzRhenVnb25DdkowNzBHNFd4YXhLQ1JKam1pTm5
iUzdLZzNiYUkxVmpUa0o1SzBER0l3RG1uSGY0bnZxTkVLd3NjTTFDeVdERGRyZEJpT2NyT2tUUzZYYkV
sR3VwZXZQR1RpS25iRE5VQThDd09xUmgrdXpzajhlK2JUNWFXL2Z4Z3lQQkZmYzZRU0prN0NjTXhydGU
ya3hJZUJpcjdkTG1pWWlvMGFXSzlGcERLclRJMDBlUDhRMVFtd2lpbFRGK3NnMXhyOWpnWXdFdG54QTZ
lbUxobHFQc1hrMUI3NSt3WWxGMXZpUWUxd3JKMVNHWlNheGJSWEsrMzBnU2g4RnRpeFcvV3lVV1p2K08
1dnRnQXQ1T0tObXQzSlV1ZXdhekxadURQSTBCbmNaR0lvV1ZKYUhmaklhdVhVZ2oyUnBWSzc1NklBMFl
uZDArbDY1UzNiQTd1TVFIRG5LT0htZ2ZRblY2ZkwwdHF6N1hrMVVhYVpxQlg1Uy9VVmFmTTNTa1lqaFM
2Sk5wN0ZYd3BZUnA5VlJVNGxwSG1henRmWmpKS3JyNnJxYzVVWkJpd2dBclp2cnVwYlJJUjFrTURIZDE
3TDV5S1NVdzc2bk5Ma2t2NlBSV1hubExLbFJpaHFscUZ1ZG9iMEN4eFI1Y0tPNkZ1Y01vUWxJRG9WRlV
aRVV0K1VFTk9SNEQrckZyVVEyZmFVaG1KcGlCcWxXQWxnU2tCb20xWk9yTnRPTjRraDEyRkp0aG1nNGJ
FMnlBWjU1VnFQNmhwK0wxZ1kxVzdlOEUyUGE1dW9hKys3UGVuVkJRY2VhMENITmhOeGFycENodUphcVJ
5TGZwZWk5QkF2c0V3bTRZUFlKS2Y4S0l6WTJoMEhCbS8xTjNENE41akQySndvQ0dIZ1JFWXNxRW9sbTB
OUEk3WXM0TlJGK1BYTlZVMysvaTNlZTcvKytpZnMiKSkpKTs="));
?>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Base64 no es encripcion. Además , El código php es server side ¿que  objeto tiene encriptarlo? ¿Puedes explicar el motivo por el que quieres hacer esto? Saludos

Comment: Mejorar la seguridad de la pagina. Ese es el objetivo.

Comment: Chequea esto, http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14546/25, la ofuscacion, no es una buena forma de hacerlo. El diseño es la mejor herramienta, elimina los vectores de ataque. Saludos.

Comment: para hacer un sito mas seguro, esta http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716 pagina puede ayudarte mucho. Saludos-.

Comment: en especial este https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Si quieres ocultar el código que estás vendiendo podrías implementar una [API](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Interfaz_de_programaci%C3%B3n_de_aplicaciones&oldid=91429691). Si solamente deseas ocultar las ubicaciones de medios (imágenes, vídeos, etc.) puedes intentar [este método](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228498-RESOLVED-Hide-Image-Source-using-PHP-and-Sessions), no lo he probado pero antes de copiar y pegar código te dará una buen idea el leerlo.

Comment: @quantme A esto era a lo que me refería pero no me acordaba de esa palabrita, API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `HTML` de la página por concepto no lo puedes encriptar: se lo estás enviando al usuario para que su navegador lo muestre, por lo tanto debe ir sin encriptar (otra cosa es que por la red viaje encriptado porque uses un certificado `HTTPS`).

Respecto al código `PHP`, los usuarios de la página nunca deberían poder ver dicho código, ya que se ejecuta en el servidor, y lo que se envía es el resultado de la ejecución. Por otra parte, el código debería estar en directorios privados, no accesibles por el usuario directamente, y solo estar en el directorio público los scripts que se ejecuten directamente desde una URL del navegador. Por ejemplo, cuando usas cualquier framework solo está accesible por web el script de entrada `index.php` y las clases están en directorios no accesibles.

Si lo que quieres es encriptar tu código `PHP` para que por ejemplo un cliente al que se lo envies no lo vea, dispones de 2 soluciones comerciales, de pago:

- http://www.ioncube.com/
- http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard

Ninguna de las 2 soporta `PHP 7`, aunque se supone que Ioncube lo hará en breve.

Base64 no es una encriptación de ningún tipo, solo es una obfuscación sencilla, que se puede revertir facilmente.

Comment: Gracias. Bueno y respecto a HTML, no se encripta el código completo, sólo las ubicaciones de la multimedia que se usa.

Comment: No se puede encriptar la ubicacion de las imagenes o videos, ya que el navegador se las tiene que poder descargar

Comment: Pues, almenos se puede "tapar" a la vista del usuario.

Comment: Puede que quieras otra cosa distinta. Pero si el usuario tiene que ver la imagen, entonces tiene que tener una URL para que el navegador se la baje. Otra cosa es que quieras que solo los usuarios logueados puedan ver imagenes, o ciertas imagenes

Comment: Pues mi finalidad es que el usuario no pueda ver las ubicaciones explícitamente, como lo hace YouTube con sus videos. Facebook con las fotos, etc.

Comment: No se a que te refieres, pero mejor haz una nueva pregunta con esa duda de las imagenes / videos

Comment: Si vas a web.whatsapp.com e inicias sesión, verás que el código que llama las imágenes de los emoji son encriptados o tapados