# Ocultar tokens en una web 100% del lado del cliente (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, api, seguridad, tokens

#### Introducción al problema

Tengo por un lado una **API REST en PHP** y por otro lado una aplicación web que consume de dicha API. El problema que tengo es que **solo quiero autorizar el uso de la API REST para mi aplicación web** (y en un futuro, para por ejemplo un app móvil).

El caso es que la mayor parte de la API REST está protegida ante eso porque sólo las peticiones con un encabezado `Authorization: Bearer "User token"` pueden obtener y solicitar recursos de dicho usuario (y que yo sepa, al no usar cookies para identificar la sesión desde el lado de la API, no hay riesgo de ataques CSRF ni ningún otro si se toman las medidas necesarias para tratar el almacenamiento de dicho token).

Sin embargo, **¿Qué hago con las rutas de inicio de sesión, registro, etc?** Estas son sin sesiones y eso quiere decir que cualquiera podría crear usuarios o iniciar sesión desde otro lugar (No es por el "spam" dado que hay límites por IP y captcha) pero no me gusta nada que pase eso por varios motivos.

#### Pregunta

La solución parece ser crear un token para cada cliente de la API que lo autorice a usarla, pero si la app está desarrollada totalmente en JavaScript, sin lenguajes del lado del servidor, **¿Cómo uso y almaceno esta token sin exponerla?**

Si es con tokens CSRF en el formulario de inicio de sesión, ¿Cómo lo implemento desde una web en JavaScript de forma que nadie más pueda simplemente hacer lo mismo?

Comment: si o si, si vas a usar tokens de autorización necesitas de lado del servidor comprobar  dicho token; ese es el uso principal de lo contrario no estarías haciendo nada, te lo digo por que así funcionan los web services.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Sí, eso lo sé, pero la pregunta del problema es "Cómo oculto el  token de la aplicación desde el lado del cliente en una aplicación hecha en JavaScript". Saludos!

Comment: a que te refieres con ocultar???, creo que lo mas que puedes hacer es almacenarla temporalmente en local storage o crear una sesion con javascirpt... pero igual seguirian disponibles... la otra manera seria de lado del servidor con la variable $_SESSION (si fuese con php) y ya no necesitarias guardar nada en javascript

Comment: Leyendo nuevamente tu pregunta (que se basa en opiniones). Yo opino que en caso de tu app web (la cual estará alojada en algún host con un dominio), puedes evitar que sea consumida por terceros simplemente estableciendo la cabecera [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) adecuada en la API Rest, esto como una medida inicial. En cuanto a la app móvil, la verdad no soy experto en las mismas y no sabría hasta qué punto puedas ocultar algún dato, sólo se me ocurre el uso de certificados. En todo caso, es mi opinión y seguro hay muchas otras. Saludos

Comment: @BrahimKhallota el companero Francisco se refiere a que esas comprobaciones siempre deberian hacerse del lado del servidor y no del lado del cliente, pues el cliente siempre va a poder tener acceso (si sabe) al token desde el cliente, es por eso que tratar de "ocultar" esta informacion desde el cliente es un tanto inutil... en su lugar tienes que pensar en el servidor 100%. ya que el usuario no podra acceder directamente al servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamento comentarte que no se puede [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237784/4717133):

> **[Traduccion]** En resumen: No, no puede proteger su clave API en una aplicación del
> lado del cliente.
> [Este artículo entra en más detalles](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/)
> Dos opciones
>
> 1. Realice las llamadas a la API del lado del servidor y luego entregue
>    información al cliente desde allí.
> 2. Requerir que el cliente use sus
>    propias claves API

Personalmente lo mas cercano seria ofuscar el token/javascript relacionado, pero esto no es considerado una buena practica [LINK](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14546/46896).

Answer (score 0):

Tanto como no poderse ocultar, pues no, hay muchas maneras de capturar la API Key como con cualquier token. Pero sí puedes prevenir el abuso generando tokens que sean de vida limitada y que no sea nada sencillo generarlos en el lado del cliente, por ejemplo los token CSRF o nonces pueden funcionar.

Una opción muy fácil de usar es los token de "autenticación" anónima de firebase, puedes generar uno al momento en que el usuario accede a la ruta de rgistro o login y limitar su duración. En donde manejas tu petición requieres que el token sea válido y si no lo es o viene sin token, rechazas la petición.

Igual que los token CSRF o nonces, como no se expone al navegador la clave que generó el token, solo en un servicio con acceso a la clave de validación se puede verificar. La ventaja con Firebase es que tienes que mantener casi nada de infraestructura y puedes enfocarte en la lógica y escribir muy poco código de validación.

En la documentación de firebase se exponen ejemplos básicos con las librerías que soportan, pero hay librerías de la comunidad para muchos lenguajes, por ejemplo yo lo implementé para Ruby y PHP:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk

Si actualizas tu pregunta con como lo has intentado y te funciona, incluso podrías mostrar aquí mismo tu solución o bien te podemos ayudar a redondear la solución.